# Debugging or Finding Errors with Serialized Data

Tags: debugging, serialization

How does one check a rather large string of serialized data for errors? Are there any debugging tools?

The closest thing i've been able to get to error reporting was an error message when trying to unserialize the data using https://www.functions-online.com/unserialize.html. The error was:

```
WARNING: Error at offset 3445 of 94242 bytes
```

I'm not sure what action to take with the above message.

Thanks for any help that can be provided!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue, and the tool you posted really helped.

The error message is telling you where it was when it broke. The string is just one long line of characters, each one is 1 byte.

Look 3445 characters into the string to find an invalid piece.

I was able to repair a large (~28000 char) string of serialized data that had 17 errors, by running it through the tool, navigating to that character, fixing the data, which was like:

```
s:25:"/content/new/"
```

into

```
s:13:"/content/new/"
```

and then when you run the string through the tool again it will break... but further along (higher offset value in error message).

Repeat this until you've manually repaired all the errors, and then it should be deserialized without an error by the tool.

Hope this helps!